# Azure app service build and deploy failing on GitHub

Tags: c#, azure, github, build

I just uploaded a very basic Xamarin mobile app to git hub.  I used the azure option to set up a service to build and deploy.  Unfortunately the GitHub build is failing in both the IOS and Android projects for the same error: Error:

> D:\a\MobileApplication\MobileApplication\MobileApplication\MobileApplication\Services\EventMockData.cs(65>,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected >[D:\a\MobileApplication\MobileApplication\MobileApplication\MobileApplication\MobileApplication.csproj]

I can't find anything wrong with the EventMockData.cs file.  and the whole project builds successfully in my local VS.

```
using MobileApplication.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MobileApplication.Services
{
    class EventMockData : IDataStore<Event>
    {
        readonly List<Event> events;

        public EventMockData()
        {
            events = new List<Event>()
            {
                new Event { id = 1,
                    eventName = "Sunday School", 
                    eventContactName = "John",
                    eventContactEmail = "john@test.com",
                    eventContactPhone = 1234567890,
                    eventImageUrl = "https://wwww.dell.com",
                    eventStartDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 04, 30, 13, 00, 00), 
                    eventEndDateTime = new DateTime(2021, 04, 30, 20, 00, 00), 
                    eventRecurrance = "daily", 
                    eventRecurranceInterval = 1, 
                    eventRecurrenceDayInterval = ""}
            };
        }
        public async Task<bool> AddItemAsync(Event item)
        {
            events.Add(item);

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public async Task<bool> UpdateItemAsync(Event item)
        {
            var oldItem = events.Where(e => e.id == item.id).FirstOrDefault(); 
            events.Remove(oldItem);
            events.Add(item);

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(int id)
        {
            var oldItem = events.Where((Event arg) => arg.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            events.Remove(oldItem);

            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public async Task<Event> GetItemAsync(int id)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(events.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == id));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(events);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's either because it's not public (different compiler versions? Doesn't like it because no one uses it?) Or try to open it with a BOM encryption and see if there are any invisible characters in the file

Comment: <ugh>  PUBLIC.  that's got to be it.  I'll try again.

Comment: Nope.  wasnt the access.